# Julia- Inheritance issues with converting 0.7 to 1.2.0

Tags: julia

I have been trying to convert some Julia code that was written in 0.7:

```
type SCA <: DiscreteMDP
nStates::Int64
nActions::Int64
actions::Vector{Symbol}
grid::RectangleGrid
function SCA()
    grid = RectangleGrid(Ranges, Thetas, Bearings, Speeds, Speeds,Responses, Responses)
    return new(NStates, NActions, Actions, grid)
end # function SCA
end # type SCA
```

The Package used, DiscreteMDP, has been deprecated and replaced with POMDPS.jl, and I am confused on how to successfully convert this. This is what I have currently:

```
mutable struct SCA <: MDP{Int64,Vector{Symbol}}#Something is wrong here
    nStates::Int64
    nActions::Int64
    actions::Vector{Symbol}
    grid::RectangleGrid
    function SCA()
        grid = RectangleGrid(Ranges, Thetas, Bearings, Speeds, Speeds, Responses, Responses)
        return new{Int64,Int64,Vector{Symbol},RectangleGrid}(NStates, NActions, Actions, grid)#Probably something Wrong here
    #Creating a new SCA does not know that MDP is a superclass. Inheritance isnt working
    end # function SCA
end # type SCA
```

From the POMDPs.jl file, there is a description of the abstract class:

```
"""
MDP{S,A}
Abstract base type for a fully observable Markov decision process.
S: state type
A: action type
"""
abstract type MDP{S,A} end
```

I am not sure where to move forward from here, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the inheritance issues here. You do have to provide us with a complete description to help you however. Can you post a complete example that worked for you in v0.7 that worked and what you tried in v1.2? For starters you need to `using GridInterpolations` in you v1.2 code, because that's where `RectangleGrid` lives. With that, you code runs fine, but your inner constructor does not work, because you're referring variables (Ranges, Thetas, Bearings, Speeds, ...) that are not present in your code, so it's impossible to help you further.